# Integrate Optaplanner with existing Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, optaplanner

Our existing application is build in Java using Spring, REST and MySQL. We now want to integrate Optaplanner in our system using Eclipse IDE. Can someone please provide a reference link to get started? The documentation on their website is not helping much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using maven, just add the maven dependency (see docs or download page) and refresh eclipse, otherwise add the jars from the bin dir from the distribution zip in eclipse.

Then look at the quick start tutorail in the docs. We don't have a spring BeanFactory wrapper yet for Solver(Factory), but that should be trivial to write, so you can inject a Solver(Factory). Or just create the SolverFactory and Solver in your java code. The domain objects are probably the same as your REST annotated objects.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Geoffrey. We got the CloudBalance example running but we are trying to solve a CVRPTW and with custom constraints and weight (for example: delivery priority is high). Can you please point us to some VehicleRoutingHelloWorld similar to CloudBalanceHelloWorld?

Comment: Take a look at `VehicleRoutingApp`. Just replace the `CloudBalanceHelloWorld`'s solver config and the CloudBalance by VehilceRoutingSolution.